# Why can't I set the memory.limit in R x64 above 4GB?

Tags: r, memory, memory-management

I can't increase my memory limit above approx 4GB in R (Windows 10). I have 128 GB of RAM. I've heard there's a bug in R studio, so I went directly into the R console. It's still not working. Ideas?

```
memory.size()
[1] 4135.24

memory.size(max=TRUE)
[1] 4196.69

memory.limit(size=128000)
[1] 130980
Warning message:
In memory.limit(size = 128000) : cannot decrease memory limit: ignored
```

And...FYI:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to set the environment variable R_MAX_MEM_SIZE with the required limit?

Comment: Alternatively, on Windows you can try to use the `--max-mem-size` option, sets the maximum memory allocation.

Comment: I created an environment variable R_MAX_MEM_SIZE and set it equal to 128GB. Still no change in output above. Confused what the output under memory.limit() means...

Comment: If var. `R_MAX_MEM_SIZE` and `memory.limit(128000)` are ignored, you can add the following line in the file .Rprofile: `invisible(utils::memory.limit(your_size_in_MB))`

Comment: Finally gave this a try in .Rprofile (took a while since I needed administrator permissions on my work machine...). Still, no luck! Same error message, this time as R starts. Warning message:
In utils::memory.limit(128000) : cannot decrease memory limit: ignored

Comment: @Allison I think this is new bug in 3.6.1.  I tried upgrading to 3.6.2 but problem still persist.  Any workaround yet?

Comment: @Ahdee no, I haven't! It's been driving me crazy. I tried upgrading also, but that didn't solve the problem. I guess the answer is downgrading, but I'm worried about impacts on libraries etc. Would very much like to know if you find a workaround.

Comment: @Allison on Rstudio you can select different version of R to use so that you can keep all your different R versions.  I just switch it over to 3.5.1 and memory allocation is working again!  Try this for now unless there is a specific package that only runs on 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is rather old, but as I don't see an answer to the question...

To increase your memory limit, specify a number greater than the value returned by

```
memory.limit(max = NA)
```

for the `size` argument in `memory.limit()`, eg,

```
memory.limit(size = 133120)
```

`memory.limit(size = 128000)` returns an error because your system's memory limit is already greater than 128000. Your current limit is 130980, the value returned by `memory.limit()`.

To see your current memory limit, run:

```
memory.limit(max = NA)
```

`memory.size(max = TRUE)` returns a relatively small value because it returns "the maximum amount of memory obtained from the OS," rather than your memory limit (see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/memory.size). (Whether that max is in the current session, ever, the current R version... I don't know.)

For comparison, on R with ~8 GB memory limit:

```r
memory.size()
#> [1] 50.7
memory.size(max = TRUE)
#> [1] 52
memory.limit(size = 1)
#> Warning in memory.limit(size = 1): cannot decrease memory limit: ignored
#> [1] 8042
memory.size(max = NA)
#> [1] 8042.05
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>